# Can I create a DataSet from a XmlSchemaSet?

Tags: c#, dataset, xsd

From somewhere else I receives a `XmlSchemaSet` object, is it possible to use it to construct a `DataSet` that uses it?

**Some background**

This `XmlSchemaSet` was read with a custom `XmlResolver`, and the original schema file have `xs:include` elements that link to other file to be resolved by the custom resolver. I confirmed that `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema` do not read these files properly even I send it a `XmlReader` with custom `XmlReaderSettings`. I think this is because `XmlReader` only resolves uris that was required by the DTD, whilst `xs:include` references are not.

**Possible solutions**

When I dig into the implementation of `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema` it seems it calls `XSDSchema.LoadSchema(schemaSet,dataSet)` method to do the job. This is what I want. But unfortunately `XSDSchema` is `internal` and not accessible unless I hack it someway.

So are there any other solutions that can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Following method worked for me. It gets the string representation of the xmlSchemaSet then reads it with StringReader which is acceptable by readXmlSchema method.

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static DataSet ToDataSet(this XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemaSet)
    {
        var schemaDataSet = new DataSet();
        string xsdSchema = xmlSchemaSet.GetString();
        schemaDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(xsdSchema));
        return schemaDataSet;
    }

    private static string GetString(this XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemaSet)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                       {
                           Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, false),
                           Indent = true,
                           OmitXmlDeclaration = false
                       };

        string output;
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                foreach (XmlSchema s in xmlSchemaSet.Schemas())
                {
                    s.Write(xmlWriter);
                }
            }
            output = textWriter.ToString();
        }
        return output;
    }
}

public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return _encoding;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "hacking" solution that seem to be works:

```
private static Action<XmlSchemaSet, DataSet> GetLoadSchemaMethod()
{
    var type = (from aN in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
        where aN.FullName.StartsWith("System.Data")
        let t = Assembly.Load(aN).GetType("System.Data.XSDSchema")
        where t != null
        select t).FirstOrDefault();

    var pschema = Expression.Parameter(typeof (XmlSchemaSet));
    var pdataset = Expression.Parameter(typeof (DataSet));
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<XmlSchemaSet, DataSet>>(Expression.Call
        (Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(new Type[] {}), new Expression[] {}),
            type.GetMethod("LoadSchema", new[]
            {
                typeof (XmlSchemaSet), typeof (DataSet)
            }), new Expression[]
            {
                pschema, pdataset
            }), new[] {pschema, pdataset});

    return exp.Compile();
}
```

However I still prefer not to do hacking.